# How to show my app on youtube share list?

Tags: android, youtube

Why it can't show my app on the youtube share list?
The current effect in the below it can't show my app..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the code to make the effect or i am using a wrong way to do the effect?

```
<activity android:name=".AboutActivity">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.send"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.default"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the other code

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MoviePlayActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_movie_play" />
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionUploadActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_question_upload" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PhotoUploadActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_upload">

    </activity>


</application>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> i am using a wrong way to do the effect?

Android is case-sensitive. Replace:

```
<activity android:name=".AboutActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.send"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.default"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

with:

```
<activity android:name=".AboutActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: For my case (HTC Butterfly S Android 5.0.2, API 21), it works after I change the replacement above from  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
to
 <data  android:mimeType="text/*"/>